# How can I replace the NULL or 0 value to dash(-) or a blank string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to return a string (-) dash, or empty value when the returned value is NULL or Zero, below is the finding, the first column ([Total 1]) is the original SUM() query, the second column ([Total 2]) is the result I want, it is working but the code is repeated and looks bulky, is there any cleaner way?

```
    SELECT 
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN ( DATEDIFF(day,OrderDate,GETDATE()) = 0 ) THEN 1 
        WHEN ( DATEDIFF(day,BookingDate,GETDATE()) = 0 ) THEN 1              
    END) AS [Total 1],
 
    (CASE 
        WHEN (SUM(CASE 
                        WHEN ( DATEDIFF(day,OrderDate,GETDATE()) = 0 ) THEN 1 
                        WHEN ( DATEDIFF(day,BookingDate,GETDATE()) = 0 ) THEN 1              
                    END) IS NULL)
        THEN '-' 
        ELSE
            CAST(SUM(CASE 
                WHEN ( DATEDIFF(day,OrderDate,GETDATE()) = 0 ) THEN 1 
                WHEN ( DATEDIFF(day,BookingDate,GETDATE()) = 0 ) THEN 1              
            END) AS VARCHAR(20))
            end 
    ) AS [Total 2]
FROM TABLE
```

Thanks.

Comment: `ISNULL`/`COALESCE`.

Comment: Use [`ISNULL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)/[`COALESCE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Thanks. I did try using them, but it will always return 0 or null. Need to use convert() too after Gordon answer. anyway, thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert the value to a string.  If you use a `CASE` expression, you need to repeat the `SUM()`.  Another method is to nest `NULLIF()` and `COALESCE()`:

```
COALESCE(NULLIF(CONVERT(VARCHAR(255),
                        SUM(CASE WHEN ( DATEDIFF(day,OrderDate,GETDATE()) = 0 ) THEN 1 
                                 WHEN ( DATEDIFF(day,BookingDate,GETDATE()) = 0 ) THEN 1              
                            END), 0
                       )
               ), '-'
        ) AS [Total 1],
```

This type of operation is rather cumbersome in SQL.  Often, it is better done in   at the application level.

Comment: Awesome!! I only tried the two combinations among the three functions in the query!! Thank you so much!